# Can't add webservice reference in C#. SOAP wrong?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I'm trying to add a reference to webservice in C# through graphical interface in Visual Studio 2010.[image]

It fails however, the error message is

**VersionMismatch Service supports SOAP version 1.1.”.**

What can I do now? I don't see any settings box where I could choose SOAP version which I use to connect to webservice???

Comment: If I remember well, you can choose the soap version when you create your project. Did you try to have a look to the project properties?

Comment: `The SOAP Response is using the SOAP 1.2 namespace declaration instead of the SOAP 1.1 namespace declaration. ` Cause of error

Comment: you can find question about the same problem on social.msdn : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f29cd9c8-3c89-43d2-92ae-d2a270ab86b9/client-and-service-binding-mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem just several days ago. Go [here](https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit?loc=en_US&rt1#) and click "Shipping" under "Developer APIs." Download *Shipping.zip* and extract it to a folder on your hard drive. Then, under the Add Service Reference window, click Advanced, click Add Web Reference, and link your WSDL file. For me, I put my files here:

```
C:\Libraries\AWSDLs\UPS\ShippingPACKAGE\PACKAGEWebServices\SCHEMA-WSDLs\Ship.wsdl
```

You may or may not need to add `file://` to the beginning of the URL depending on your VS version.

Comment: I did it this way to go on with the project. But what if I didn't have .wsdl file??? I'm still interested in answers

Comment: When I contacted UPS tech support, I was told that this is the way to go about it now. I don't know why they would do that, as it was certainly far easier before. Both FedEx and UPS have this problem.